# How do I prevent render-blocking for CSS loaded via HTML Imports?

Tags: css, polymer, web-component, pagespeed, html-imports

I'm creating a web site using **Web Components** and **Polymer** loading assets via **HTML Imports**.

My markup looks something like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script src="vendor/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js" async></script>
  <link rel="import" href="assets.html" />
</head>

<body>
```

In `assets.html` I explicitly load the CSS in a way that should avoid render-blocking:

```
<link rel="import" href="vendor/polymer/polymer-mini.html" />
<link href="main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="import" href="header.html" />
```

However, when I run my site through Google's [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) I get the following error:

> Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content
>
> Your page has 2 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.
>
> None of the above-the-fold content on your page could be rendered without waiting for the following resources to load. Try to defer or asynchronously load blocking resources, or inline the critical portions of those resources directly in the HTML.
>
> Optimize CSS Delivery of the following:
>
> http://is-aws-assets.divshot.io/main.min.css
>
> http://fonts.googleapis.com/…y=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,90

What is confusing to me is that Google's own, official [Optimize CSS Delivery](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery) guide states clearly that HTML Imports should load CSS without render-blocking:

> Note that the web platform will soon support loading stylesheets in a non-render-blocking manner, without having to resort to using JavaScript, using HTML Imports.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug with PageSpeed Insights?

Comment: Do you need that many font weights? You can gain some speed by using just 2 font weights rather than 6 of them.    http://fonts.googleapis.com/…y=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,90? <== =(I assume that's 900.)    400 for body and 700 for headings is all you should need.

Answer (score 2):

the documentation is right, even though a little ambiguous.

`<link>` is not non-blocking by default, when it hits a nested CSS resources it blocks rendering.

try adding the `async` attribute like so:

`<link rel="import" ... async>`.

http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/imports/#link-type-import

Comment: I seem to get the same error message on PageSpeed Insights when I add the `async` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the size of your CSS you could also consider inlineing a large portion if not all of the CSS in the head of your element, rather than making a blocking request.

That way you won't have a flash of unstyled content like you would with the async approach, and you wouldnt be blocking your content from displaying.

Comment: I understand why people do this but it seems to defeat the point of CSS: separating content from style. It's a shame it seems to be the only solution to this problem.